# Неправильный расчёт даты возврата книг

Tags: php, mysqli

Я написал код для подсчёта количества дней, через которые должны вернуть книги, взятые в библиотеке, но, к сожалению, код не правильно считает.

```
<?php
$student=$_GET["student"];
//For semestr books
$StudentInfo = "SELECT * FROM book_week WHERE student_id = {$student} AND expired = 0";
$ListInfoResult = mysqli_query($connection, $StudentInfo);

$currentDate = (int)date('G');

while($ListRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ListInfoResult))
    {
         //СЧИТАЕТ КОЛ_ВО ОСТАВШИХСЯ ДНЕЙ
$ExpireTime = $ListRow['date_expiration'] - $currentDate;

        if($ExpireTime > 0){
?>

<a href="admin_library_del_book.php?book=<?php echo $ListRow["book_name"]; ?>&student=<?php echo $student?>"><?php echo $ListRow["book_name"]; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $ExpireTime ?><br />

<?php
    }else{
        $Book_name = $ListRow["book_name"];
        $UpdateExpire = "UPDATE book_week SET expired = 1 WHERE book_name = '{$Book_name}' LIMIT 1";
        $UpdateExpireResult = mysqli_query($connection, $UpdateExpire);


         }
}//WHILE braces
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке показан результат, что выводится, и что есть в базе.

Учитывая сегодняшнее число 22, и то, что в базе в колонке book_name лежит wdw c истекающем днём 23, то в результате сайт должен показывать 1, а не 4.

Где проблема в коде?

Comment: Что вообще не понятно, как вы при таком подходе хотите решить свою задачу. То что `date('G')` возвращает текущее _количество часов_, т.е. сейчас в 17:57 оно должно вернуть 17, это еще ничего. Даже если вы получите текущий день, то когда у вас наступит expire по записи у которой стоит date_expiration 36 ? Ведь 36 дней не бывает ни в одном месяце. И если вдруг пропустили 31 число (т.к. это воскресенье и никого нет на работе), когда что то должно было истеч и началось 1 февраля, то уже будем ждать 31 марта ... В базу надо класть ДАТУ окончания и прямо в базе сравнивать с now().

Comment: И вообще весь ваш php скрипт легко выполняется одним sql запросом без какой либо логике на php

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как,... Просто на сайте я указываю через ск дней должны вернуть книгу, эти дни плюсуются к текущей дате и поэтому получилось 36

Comment: Открываете например http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html  изучаете что может mysql с датами делать. Делаете колонку типа date, а не int. Когда добавляете книгу дату например на 25 дней у записи ставите дату равную `date_add(now(), interval 25 day)`. Все, в записи лежит конкретная дата на 25 дней больше текущей. Выбираете все истекшие даты `select * from table where date_exp<now()`. И мне интересно как вы дадите двум людям 2 экземпляра войны и мира, названия то у экземпляров одинаковые ..

Comment: Спасибо огромное.....Там так же будет сравниваться по пользователю, и когда происходит выборка из базы то достаётся только та книга которая соответствует пользователю в сессии.Или это тоже не правильно?

Comment: @pavel Скорее всего неправильно. От задачи зависит. Вот обнаружат на полке испорченный экземпляр, захотят узнать кто конкретно этот экземпляр последний раз брал. И как они искать будут, если с таким названием несколько книг. А если при выдаче в названии книги буквой одной ошиблись, то это уже совсем другая книга выходит. По хорошему, должна быть отдельная таблица, со списком всех экземпляров в библиотеке и их названия там. А в таблице выдачи книг - только id экземпляра книги. И потом по этому id сразу можно будет всю историю этого экземпляра получить